# Batch set /a variable tally doesn't echo into text file until value is at least 10

Tags: loops, batch-file, echo

I am developing a batch script which does a repeating robocopy.  It then tallies the number of runs it has performed and echos the number into a text file.  It repeats the tally and echo each time that it repeats the robocopy.

The problem I am having is that it does not start echoing the tally number into the text file until the value of the tally has reached at least 10.

I have discovered that this is easily repeatable.  For example,

```
set /a TALLY=0
:START
echo %TALLY%>>C:\TEMP\tally.txt
set /a TALLY=%TALLY%+1
goto :START
```

If you run the above batch file, you will see that the text file starts with a line that says "ECHO ON" and then proceeds to start counting beginning at 10.

Can anyone explain what's going on here and how I might get my tally to start with 1?

Comment: Put the redirection first.  It thinks you are defining a file stream. `>>C:\TEMP\tally.txt echo %TALLY%`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  Based on your answer, I discovered that putting a space immediately prior to the double chevrons also solves this since it prevents the %TALLY% variable from being interpreted as a stream number.
 
Is it considered best practice to echo messages into a text file in the way that you describe?

Comment: No. You are tricking the parser. `Num>` means redirect THAT file number. 0 to 9. Space is best practise.

Comment: if you don't want the space to be in the outputfile, use parantheses: `(echo %TALLY%)>>C:\TEMP\tally.txt` or turn the syntax: `>>C:\TEMP\tally.txt echo %tally%`

Comment: @bgalea if you use a space that space is output to the file. I do not consider it tricking the parser and using a space is not a best practice in my book.

Comment: @Squashman Write your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
set /a TALLY=0
:START
echo %TALLY%>>C:\TEMP\tally.txt
set /a TALLY=%TALLY%+1 >> C:\TEMP\tally.txt
goto :START
```

this might work